# Is there an STL-like function to fill an array with some function of the index?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

In C++ we have functions like `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` which are convenient one-liner ways of filling pointer-arrays, vectors, `std::array`s and other containers with values. Some containers also have their own `fill` methods to allow filling with a constant value. There are also the functions `std::generate{_n}` and `std::iota`, the former of which allows filling the elements using a generator function and the latter of which fills the range with indices.

What I am looking for is a similar solution - preferrably a one-liner solution and defined in the standard library - that allows filling the container with some function of the index. For example, this would be a solution for an array:

```
std::array<int, 100> arr;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    arr[i] = f(i);
```

where `f(std::size_t i)` is some function of the index.

Is there an  integrated way of doing this?

Comment: why don't you use std::generate_n ? it is exactly what you want

Comment: Is this what you want? https://wandbox.org/permlink/tAwaouhYJtacJNjt

Comment: @Oblivion That would be a solution, however, I am looking for something more generic that does not rely on static variables. For example a function that accepts a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing your own *STL-like* function template, `apply_idx_func()`, for that:

```
template<typename FwdItor, typename F>
void apply_idx_func(FwdItor first, FwdItor last, F f) {
   for (size_t idx = 0; first != last; ++first, ++idx)
      *first = f(idx);
}
```

As an example:

```
auto main() -> int {
   std::array<int, 10> arr;

   // just adds 100 to the index
   auto func = [](size_t idx) -> int {
      return 100 + idx;
   };

   apply_idx_func(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), func);

   for (auto elem: arr)
      std::cout << elem << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
```

Comment: Is there some recommendation of "where" to put custom extension? For example which namespace?

Comment: @HerpDerpington you can create your own namespace, e.g.: `namespace xtd { ... }` (**xtd** would stand for *eXtended sTandarD*, in contrast to the `std` namespace).

Answer (score 7):

You could use a stateful lambda:

```
std::array<int, 100> arr;   
std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [i = std::size_t(0)]() mutable {return f(i++);});
```

---

But I think it makes the code more complex than it needs to be. Using a plain loop might be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't try this with a compiler since I couldn't find one with C++20 ranges, but something like this should work once compilers implement them:

```
std::ranges::transform(std::views::iota{1, arr.size()+1}, arr, f);
```

or, if you just want the sequence of generated values, just create a range of them with

```
auto const values = std::views::iota{1, arr.size()+1} | std::views::transform(f);
```

Until you have a C++20 compiler, you can use one of the range libraries, e.g. in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) or [Eric Nieblers ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Comment: If destination really need to be a `std::array`, a step is missing though: convert the view into array.

Comment: not even gcc.godbolt.org seems to know about this, it's that new :( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pgh7uS

Answer (score 1):

If you always go through the whole array, you don't even have to use any stl function, just use range loop:

```
std::array<int, 100> arr;
int idx = 0;
for (auto& item : array)
    item = f(idx++);
```

Another option is to use `for_each` (this can be more useful, if in the future you want to fill your array *only partially*)

```
#include <algorithm>
std::array<int, 100> arr;
int idx = 0;
std::for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), [&idx](int &n){ n = f(idx++); });
```

Unfortunately, in both cases, you have to have separate variable for index (here: `idx`)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
size_t i = 0;
std::generate_n(arr.begin(),arr.size(),[&i](){return f(i++);});
```

Or possibly in two steps:

```
#include <numeric>
std::iota(arr.begin(),arr.end(),0);
std::transform(arr.begin(),arr.end(),f);
```

With the help of boost we can do this in one step:

```
std::transform(
    arr.begin(),
    arr.end(),
    boost::irange(0,arr.size()),
    [](const auto& val,const auto& index){return f(index);}
);
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html